# Regression of NDVI data

Tags: distributions, mixed-model

I would like to estimate the relationship between NDVI data and gradient in a particular network while accounting for watershed (random effect).

I would usually run a mixed effects model, but the NDVI data is  bounded between -1 & 1. So, I cannot use a glmm and specify a distribution for the NDVI data because I cannot find a distribution that the data will conform to due to the bounded nature.

What distribution could/should I use (or what analysis) to understand this relationship? If I can also account for spatial autocorrelation that would be ideal.

Comment: Because NDVI is not a direct measurement--it's a derived quantity--one approach to consider would be regression of its components followed by a *post hoc* calculation of the NDVI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NDVI is jargon in remote sensing for normalized difference vegetation index. See
[e.g. Wikipedia on the topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_difference_vegetation_index). It is no disrespect to guess that perhaps 1% of the readership here know that already.

Arguably, here "vegetation" is optimistic as a signal that it is hoped that the measure indicates something about vegetation, while "index" is redundant as "normalized difference" is slightly informative and "index" adds nothing.

That aside, the boundedness of the measure suggests to me working with

(NDVI $+\ 1) / 2$

as bounded between $0$ and $1$ and therefore suited for (e.g.) generalized linear models with logit link, but noting that an approximately continuous response calls for variance-robust standard errors.

You can rescale predictions back to the original scale by $(2\ \times$ predicted) $-1$.

I don't have simple suggestions, or even complicated ones, about handling spatial autocorrelation. When this is done there are usually thousands of data points, but confidence intervals and P-values will be at best indications in practice.